# Hibernation/Suspend effects on encoding process

Tags: multimedia

What if I suspend or hibernate my PC while encoding a video using HandBrake?
Does it somehow affect the result? (ex: suspended at 33,06%, get a defective B frame in that place)
And what if I "Pause" the process before suspending/hibernating?

Comment: I know, I deserve to be beaten up for behaving like a 3 years old non-stop-questioning child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it has no affect.  Only real time sensitive things can be negatively impacted by suspending, such as network connections or recording live video.